# how to sort describe-variable completion list by recency (or frequency)?

Tags: helm, completion, variables, sorting

When I run `describe-variable`, then choose something, I often wind up looking at the same variable again later or next session. However, when I do `describe-variable` again, the `helm` list of variables that pops up is completely random, showing me variables I'll never use.

[image]

It would be much more useful to show me a list of my most recently described variables, as `recentf` does with files.

Is this possible? I use helm, and I see that `helm-adaptive-mode` is on. It would be great to make this work with other commands too, e.g. if `load-theme` would show me my most recently (or commonly) used themes instead of showing me a list of themes in random order.

Related, but didn't help me: [Is there any way to order helm results by commonly used?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5311/is-there-any-way-to-order-helm-results-by-commonly-used)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not get a satisfactory answer for Helm, and if you are not limited to Helm and are open to another solution, you can use [Icicles](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) to do what you want.

You can [sort completion candidates](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Sorting_Candidates) in general, not just for `describe-variable`, and a few of the sort orders are for recency of use.